# Postgres get rows with one same column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres I have a table as below:

Table `phones`

```
 |id | phone        |
 | 1 | +12345678    |
 | 2 | +95687445    |
 | 3 | +78945646    |
 | 4 | +12345678    |
```

As you can see `id` `1` and `4` have the same phone number.

I want to get all rows which has same phone number but different `id` like this:

```
 | id1 | id2 | phone     |
 | 1   | 4   | +12345678 |
```

I have tried to use `JOIN` with itself but that returns duplicate results:

```sql
select
  p1.id as id1,
  p2.id as id2,
  p1.phone
from phones as p1
  join phones as p2
    on p1.phone = p2.phone
```

```
 | id1 | id2 | phone     |
 | 1   | 4   | +12345678 |
 | 4   | 1   | +12345678 |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend `array_agg()`:

```
select phone, array_agg(id)
from phones
group by phone;
```

This handles more than two results.

If you specifically want pairs, use `join` with a filtering condition:

```
select p1.id as id1, p2.id as id2, p1.phone
from phones p1 join
     phones as p2
     on p1.phone = p2.phone and
        p1.id < p2.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the not equal condition for the IDs:

```
select
  p1.id as id1,
  p2.id as id2,
  p1.phone
from phones as p1
  join phones as p2
    on p1.phone = p2.phone
where p1.id < p2.id
```

You'll have duplications in case of more than 2 identical values... For the complete solution, the query is much more complicate.

Comment: I'd try `where p1.id < p2.id`. To avoid switched duplicates.

Comment: Yes, even better, fixed the answer